# How can i convert my Installer build from packagesbuild to productbuild?

Tags: macos, app-store, productbuild

I have built an Installer for mac os using [packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html). Now I want to upload it to app store. But apple complains saying the installer should be built either with Xcode or productbuild. I guess I won't be able to use Xcode since my codebase for the app is in python.

I have installer plugins (registration and 1 more plugin) as well which are developed in objective c. I also have pre and post install scripts to run after each component is copied to the user's machine.

Is there any way i can port the installer building from mac packages's packagesbuild to productbuild?

I came across this documentation for product build:
https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/productbuild/
but it does not talk about post install scripts for each component.

Comment: It is possible to create an Xcode Run Script Build phase utilizing `Packages`...

Comment: @l'L'l Can you please link me with some posts?

Answer (score 5):

Using `pkgbuild`, it's still possible to include preinstall and postinstall scripts for each of the component packages.

You can then use `productbuild` to build the installer out of the component packages. There are some options for including scripts in the product installer, though it doesn't use the same `preinstall`/`postinstall` setup. Instead, you'll need to use the product distribution file to include and call scripts.

I found this link to be extremely helpful in getting a handle on the whole process: https://matthew-brett.github.io/docosx/flat_packages.html